# Access form ressources from code in VS 2015 (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, localization, visual-studio-2015

Good morning,

Context:
I have a localized VB.NET form, called Menu.vb
The localization is activated, so I have multiple ressource files attached, Menu.resx, Menu.fr-FR.resx...

I have added a custom string to those ressources files, and I would like to display this string in a MsgBox, depending on the culture selected.

Problem:
I can't access the form ressource from within the form code.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks a lot,
Maxime

Comment: `Problem: I can't access the form ressource from within the form code.` Show what you have tried to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager` to access the form resources:

```
// inside the form code - 'this' represents the Form instance
Dim resources As ComponentResourceManager = New ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType())

// get the string you want
resources.GetString("nameOfTheStringResource")

// optionally you can access the same with specific culture
resources.GetString("nameOfTheStringResource", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```